# redirecting output of pexpect to a file

Tags: python, io-redirection, pexpect

I tried to capture the output of pexpect in a file.

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56)
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pexpect
>>> child = pexpect.spawn('iostat 3')
>>> fout = file('mylogfile.txt','w')
>>> child.logfile = fout
```

```
tazim@webdev:~/webexample$ ps -ef | grep iostat
tazim     4683  4675  0 12:49 pts/3    00:00:00 /usr/bin/iostat 3
tazim     4685  4560  0 12:51 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto iostat
```

However `mylogfile.txt` does not receives the output. The file is created but is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to expect something from the child :)
Add this, for instance:

```
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```